# Does someone know a way to solve this integral analytically?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I have an integral as follows:
$$
-2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\int_{\lvert r_e-r \rvert}^{r_e+r} \rho_p(r_p) r_p dr_p dr
$$
where
$$
\rho_p(r_p)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}\gamma^{3/2}}{\pi^{3/2}}*\exp^{-2r_p^2 \gamma}
$$
where $\gamma$ is a constant and finally I should obtain a function in term of $r_e$.
I tried it by Mathematica but it couldn't solve it and just gives the initial following answer:
$$
-2\pi\int_0^{\infty} \frac{-\exp^{-2(r+r_e)^2\gamma}+\exp^{-2\gamma \lvert r-r_e \rvert ^2}}{\sqrt{2}\pi^{3/2}} dr
$$
I'm not an expert in mathematics so have no idea. However I'm sure there are some masters in this forum which can help me. Any suggestion?

**Addendum**

Answer of @CVolk gives the correct result, I have compared this answer with numerical integration by Mathematica in the following photo and as you can see they are match

[image]

Comment: The indefinite integral over $r_p$ is not difficult since ${d\over dr}\exp(-r^2)=-2r\exp(-r^2)$. Maybe you could show what you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes, Mathematica can integrate over rp but it has trouble with integrating over r. I added its initial answer.

Comment: Perhaps Mathematica is flummoxed by writing $\exp^{-2r_p^2 \gamma}$ instead of $\exp(-2r_p^2 \gamma)$ or $e^{-2r_p^2 \gamma}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\space\space\space$I think I see the problem that Mathematica is having....

Let $m={2\sqrt{2}\gamma^{3/2}\over\pi^{3/2}}$
Then we have,

$$-2m\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{|r_e-r|}^{r_e+r}e^{-2r_p^2\gamma}r_pdr_pdr$$

Letting u=$2r_p^2\gamma$ yields the following,

$${-2m\pi\over4\gamma}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{2(r-r_e)^2\gamma}^{2(r_e+r)^2\gamma}e^{-u}dudr$$

Which gives us,

$${-2m\pi\over4\gamma}\int_{0}^{\infty}\big(-e^{-2\gamma(r_e+r)^2}+e^{-2\gamma(r-r_e)^2}\big)dr$$

Splitting the integral over the sum and another round of substitutions...

$${2m\pi\over4\gamma}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\gamma(r_e+r)^2}dr-{2m\pi\over4\gamma}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\gamma(r-r_e)^2}dr$$

Lettting k=$\sqrt{2\gamma}(r_e+r)$ and j=$\sqrt{2\gamma}(r-r_e)$...

$${2m\pi\over4\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\int_{r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}^{\infty}e^{-k^2}dk-{2m\pi\over4\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\int_{-r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}^{\infty}e^{-j^2}dj$$

$\space\space\space$These integrals are both special cases of the "Complementary Error Function" which has no elementary antiderivative. You can, however, get a somewhate nice answer...

The Complementary Error Function $"erfc(x)"$ is defined as:

$${2\over\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$$

There is a relation between this function and the Error Function "$erf(x)$" which states that $$erfc(x)=1-erf(x)$$
Where the Error Function is defined as:

$${2\over\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}dt$$

Applying the previous definitions yields;

$${2m\pi\over4\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\bigg(-\int_{0}^{r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}e^{-k^2}dk+\int_{0}^{-r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}e^{-j^2}dj\bigg)$$

Which we can write thusly;

$${-2m\pi\over4\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\bigg(\int_{-r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}^{r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}e^{-x^2}dx\bigg)$$

Expanding the exponential as an infinite sum gives us,

$${-2m\pi\over4\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over{n!}}\int_{-r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}^{r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}}x^{2n}dx$$

Which finally gives us an answer to the original integral;

$${-m\pi\over\gamma\sqrt{2\gamma}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over{n!}(2n+1)}\big(r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}\big)^{2n+1}$$

Unpacking m gives us a little simplification as well...

$${-2\over\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over{n!}(2n+1)}\big(r_e\sqrt{2\gamma}\big)^{2n+1}$$

Comment: thanks a lot. your solution worked. see my addendum.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help...